# Website with Https does not work on IE 8

Tags: https, internet-explorer-8

I recently moved by site to https and i have many users from xp and ie8.
Just noticed website with https not working as per screenshot below:

[image]

AS per my research on similar topics:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968089

Microsoft says, you cannot view the site until you make some changes into your browsers, which is not possible to explain to every user who has IE browser.

Similarly, when i view **Google** on ie8 it works fine, so any one guide me what is the solution?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @SLaks I know - hence deleted comment :)

Comment: I am using https://www.vidahost.com/ for my website and certificate i am using is: https://www.vidahost.com/page/ssl-certificates the first package.

Comment: Analyze your website with [SSL Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/), it can help you identify the cause.